# Integrate a document viewer in my website like Firmroom

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-viewer, angular, documentation-viewer

I am working on a website with Vanilla Js and PHP, where one user can upload files of format (pdf, doc, ppt, excel) and share with others but others can only view file in the website only instead of downloading it.
What I want to create is something like this website [firmroom.com](https://firmroom.com)

I have created a free account here and check I can upload documents and can View it on the website instead of downloading it

Here are some the screenshots

I have uploaded these docs.

[image]

And can view it on their viewer.

[image]

[image]

Here I can see they have used [flow paper viewer](https://flowpaper.com/).

But the flowpaper site it is said it only works for PDF 
How they are showing excel and other doc files then.

This is what I observed from them.

If there is any similar solution, plugin or tool rather than google or Microsoft embedded viewer
as I do not want users to download directly and expose public URL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider a commercial product, you could look at the LEADTOOLS Document Viewer for web (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor that distributes the LEADTOOLS SDK)

It can load and save different types of documents including all of the Office formats (without using MSO) as well as PDF.

You can test it yourself with your files at the following online demo:
https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/index.html

Here is a screenshot of the DocumentViewer:

[image: demo ss]